# SSL routines:SSL_CTX_set_cipher_list:no cipher match

Tags: encryption, nginx, ssl, openssl, hash

I have Ubuntu=20.04 server running (Openssl=1.1.1t & nginx=1.21.6). I allowed ssl ciphers as

```
cat nginx.conf | grep -i ssl_ciphers
        ssl_ciphers 'ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-CCM:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-CCM:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-GCM-SHA256:CHACHA20-POLY1305-SHA256:TLS_AES_128_CCM_SHA256:TLS_AES_128_CCM_8_SHA256';
```

As per the official documentatin of openssl (Ref: https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man1/ciphers.html) the ciphers TLS_AES_128_CCM_SHA256 & TLS_AES_128_CCM_8_SHA256 are supported.

While I try to connect to the target machine using

```
# openssl s_client -connect 192.168.2.15:443 -ciphersuites TLS_AES_128_CCM_SHA256 -tls1_3
139638440334656:error:0200206F:system library:connect:Connection refused:../crypto/bio/b_sock2.c:110:
139638440334656:error:2008A067:BIO routines:BIO_connect:connect error:../crypto/bio/b_sock2.c:111:
connect:errno=111
```

I am unable to track what actually I am missing here.

Answer (score 0):

TLS 1.3 ciphers can not be set with `ssl_ciphers`. They need to be configured with `ssl_conf_command Ciphersuites`:

```
ssl_conf_command Ciphersuites 'TLS_AES_128_CCM_SHA256:TLS_AES_128_CCM_8_SHA256';
```